# In IntelliJ, how can I view the generated docs in the browser, using Shift + F1

Tags: java, intellij-idea, external, javadoc, shortcut

When I use **Tools | Generate JavaDoc**, for a class or project, I can browse to the directory and open the generated documents in HTML format by clicking on them. But I cannot figure out a way to open the HTML doc, from the IntelliJ using **Shift + F1**. I added the destination directory to the "Project Structure -> SDKs -> Documentation Paths" but that did not help. I wonder what am I missing?

P.S.1 Configuring the official JavaDoc from Oracle URL is not a problem and works like a charm, What I am trying to do is to use Shift + F1 to open docs that I had generated.

P.S.2 I check "**Include JDK and library sources in sourcepath**" and "**Link to JDK documentation**" options when I generate the docs, but that does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generated JavaDoc folder needs to be added in the Project Structure dialog for the module in the **Paths** tab:

[image: JavaDoc]