# In Android studio, how can I view the generated docs in the browser, using Shift + F1

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, documentation

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60709137/in-intellij-how-can-i-view-the-generated-docs-in-the-browser-using-shift-f1), in IntelliJ, after generating docs, you can add the local documents to your project so when you are working on the project, you can use Shift + F1 to open the documents classified in the browser. I want to do the same thing in Android Studio, but the project structure in Android Studio is so different.

I have checked many questions here on Stackoverflow and elsewhere, but did not find an answer that does the trick.

As it is explained in many answers, I want to make it clear that I do NOT want to sync documents for imported libraries or jar files, I also know how to generate the docs and store them locally, **what I need is to use the docs that I generated from my own java files, in the same way that I can reach to developer.android.com documents by simply clicking on the methods and pressing Shift + F1.**

Thanks in advance for any help.